# Capture event when iframe content changes

Tags: jquery, events, iframe, rich-text-editor, sceditor

I'm using [SCEditor](http://sceditor.com/) plugin
 as the rich editor. This plugin generates an iframe inside my html page. When I type every thing, this editor adds some html element inside that iframe. Now, I need to **capture event on changing iframe content.** How can I do this?

This is the html code that plugin generates:

```
<div id="editor" ... >
     ...
    <iframe>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
          <head>...</head>
          <body>
              //This content changes when i type every thing
          </body>
      </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$(pointerToContainerEditor).sceditor('instance')
```

(consider $(pointerToContainerEditor) a variable containing the same as you used with the `.sceditor()` method to initialize SCE.)
To get the editor instance you are using. Then use the methods

http://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/bind/
+
http://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/val/

Use `.bind()` to add an event listener to the editor. The most common DOM events are available.
Use `.val()` get the current value at the current mode. Read the links above for more information, feel free to ask if you still didn't get it.